# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.ResultReceiver cannot be cast to com.hello.utils.network.MyReciever

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-intentservice

i am trying to use a custom ResultReciever from an intent into a intentService but i get this bizare error.

any ideas why?

Followed this guide in using resulReciever as callbacks

http://lalit3686.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html

Here is my code from activity that starts service:

```
private void doNetworkInitCalls() {
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NetworkService.class);
    intent.setAction(NetworkService.ACTION_GET_CITY_INFO);
    intent.putExtra(NetworkService.EXTRA_LATLON, new LatLon(51.5073, 0.1276));
    MyReciever reciever = new MyReciever(null);
    reciever.setOnCityInfoRecieved(this);
    intent.putExtra(MyReceiver.RESULT_RECEIEVER_EXTRA, reciever);
    startService(getCityInfoIntent);
}
```

MyReciever class:

```
public class MyReciever extends ResultReceiver {

    public static final String RESULT_CITY_INFO = "cityInfoData";
    public static final String RESULT_RECEIEVER_EXTRA = "reciever";

    public MyReciever(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
    }
}
```

IntentService:

```
public class NetworkService extends IntentService {

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     if (intent != null) {
         MyReciever reciever = intent.getParcelableExtra(MyReciever.RESULT_RECEIEVER_EXTRA); //fails on this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Reciever, Receiver, Receiever ..? (check typos)

Comment: sorry bad paste. edited the snippet above

Comment: Show your ResultReceiver.java class

Comment: What is `getCityInfoIntent`? Shouldn't you be doing `startService(intent);` instead?

Comment: problem is that only ResultReceiver "part" of MyReciever is serialized to parcel ... the link that you provide is has misleading code, parcel serialization is by value not by reference so you dont have the same object on the other side but is it recreated intance ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about this :

```
public class NetworkService extends IntentService {

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     if (intent != null) {
         ResultReceiver reciever = intent.getParcelableExtra(MyReciever.RESULT_RECEIEVER_EXTRA);
    }
}
```

As CREATOR has not been redefined in MyReciever, it creates ResultReceiver instances. Just receive your ResultReceiver instance from the intent as it is, a ResultReceiver.

Comment: Doesnt that lose the reference to my actual CustomResultReciever?

Comment: No, the reciever is still a MyReciever, but seen by NetworkService as a ResultReceiver

Comment: This was not my experience. I cannot type cast to child of the ResultReceiver. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?